# With CSS is there a way I can make my cursor change to a finger when I hover over a button if it's not disabled?

Tags: css

I have buttons on my form. When I hover over these my cursor stays as a pointer. Is there a way that I can make it change to a hand with a finger but ONLY when the button is not disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can with CSS3 selectors:

```
button:not([disabled]) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or alternatively, provide a style for the regular button and a different one  for the disabled button:

```
button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8SbAw/

Answer (score 0):

Yes set your button's style to

```
{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=pointer

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
button:hover:disabled{
cursor: pointer;
}
button:active:disabled{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: `:active` is not "not disabled".

Comment: @BoltClock will this do

Comment: No because the question is asking for elements that are *not* disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check the JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/PYPHH/

```
<input type="button" id="new">

#new:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```